# virtual machines in Data center with SDN

Tags: networking, virtualbox

If I have big data center and i dynamically rent virtual machines (segments) to different users, how can I put all of these virtual machines on same network (segment to communicate fast and isolate from other segments (to be specific on one switch) without manually plugging the cables in and out?

Little insight : I'm currently working on SDN and what's SDN and how it works and stumbled upon this problem but can't seem to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Managing networks in virtualization is done in the hypervisor. You would connect all available ports on the server and use virtual switches, subnets, and VLANs to manage the traffic flow.

To give an example in VMWare:

```
Port 1 - Server management interface
Port 2 - VSwitch 1 - VLANs 10-100
Port 3 - VSwitch 2 - VLANs 101-200
etc.
```